# "missing argument -c" when restarting Unicorn via Mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, unicorn

I am trying to deploy my app to my server using Mina and I need the server to be restarted automatically. But unfortunately this doesn't work and I don't know why. Here is what I am trying:

```
require 'mina/bundler' 
require 'mina/rvm' 
require 'mina/rails' 
require 'mina/git' 

...

set :unicorn_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/unicorn.rb"
set :unicorn_pid, "#{deploy_to}/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

...
task :environment do
  invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-2.2.3]'
end

task deploy: :environment do
  deploy do
    # Put things that prepare the empty release folder here.
    # Commands queued here will be run on a new release directory.
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths' 
    invoke :'bundle:install' 

    invoke :'rails:db_migrate' 
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile' 

    invoke :restart_server
  end
end

task :restart_server do
  if File.exists? unicorn_pid
    queue 'kill `cat #{unicorn_pid}`'
  end
  queue 'bundle exec unicorn -c #{deploy_to}/#{unicorn_conf} -E production -D'
  puts "bundle exec unicorn -c #{deploy_to}/#{:unicorn_conf} -E production -D"
end
```

This last `puts` statement, I put it just to debug and it prints the string I want. But I still got this error:

```
 /home/webuser/tmpcms/tmp/build-145333668721611/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn:110:in `block in <top (required)>': missing argument: -c (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
   from /home/webuser/tmpcms/tmp/build-145333668721611/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn:10:in `new'
   from /home/webuser/tmpcms/tmp/build-145333668721611/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn:10:in `<top (required)>'
   from /home/webuser/tmpcms/tmp/build-145333668721611/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
   from /home/webuser/tmpcms/tmp/build-145333668721611/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
   !       bash: line 209: log: command not found
!     ERROR: Deploy failed.
```

I don't know what causes it, can you help me with it?

UPD: It seems to be something with the variable substitution and `fetch` function, but I still can't understand what is wrong. Here is what I've tested:

```
task :restart_server => :environment do
  if File.exists? unicorn_pid
    queue 'kill `cat #{unicorn_pid}`'
  end
  queue 'cd /home/webuser/tmpcms/current; pwd; bundle exec unicorn -c #{deploy_to}/#{unicorn_conf} -E production -D'
end
```

`bundle exec` part doesn't work, it doesn't execute it and prints `Connection closed` instead. The same thing if I will replace the path in the `cd` command with `cd #{deploy_to}` or to `cd #{fetch(:deploy_to)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my, the answer was so easy.
I forgot that I was using single quotes instead of double quotes, and the variables weren't substituted there needed.
Just replacing single quotes with double quotes solved it.